# Treat Hypothetical Entities as Proper Nouns?

Tags: proper-nouns, mathematics

I am working with mathematical papers and commonly encounter situations where the author designates hypothetical entities. For example:

> We assume that ***player 1*** moves first.

Should references to hypothetical (otherwise unnamed) players such as ***player 1*** be capitalized?

Comment: It basically just depends on the style guide used by the paper's publisher. You can verify this by [searching Google scholar for "player 1"](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=%22player+1%22) and observing that both capitalized and uncapitalized versions abound.

Comment: I see your point, but it is somewhat unsatisfying. There should be a definitive answer either way.  For example if player 1 referred to a specific person then certainly the term would be capitalized.  Since player 1's identity is ambiguous it seems like a call to not capitalize the term.

Comment: In chess, *White* and *Black* are usually capitalized. In bridge, *East, West, North,* and *South* are also usually capitalized. So I'd recommend taking your cue from that and capitalizing *Player 1* and *Player 2*. (In card games, *the dealer* is usually lowercase, but that is more like the expression *the first player*, which I wouldn't capitalize.)

Comment: @Colin, for what it's worth, I'd capitalize. One rule of thumb that many English language learners hear is, *if you can put "the" in front of a word, then it's not a proper noun*. Of course, this rule has about 9,001 exceptions, but it seems to apply well enough here (i.e., you wouldn't say "the player 1", so treat it like a proper noun and capitalize it.)

Comment: @Colin But why need there be a definitive answer? And who would make it definitive?

Comment: Thank you for the solid commentary.  Summarizing, if there are only well defined players then the comments support capitalizing.  However, in the case where the author refers to "the _ith_ player", "player _i_" should not be capitalized as it is equivalent to the aforementioned case of stating "the first player".   More generally, capitalize if the players are well-defined entities, such as _White_ and _Black_ in chess or in a scenario with a set number of players such as a two player game, and do not capitalize if the players are abstract enumerated entities.

Comment: @choster I think languages should be internally consistent when possible.  So if some sensible logic can be built up around an approach then I prefer to go with the supported method.  Of course there are many cases that come down to style and that is OK too.

Answer (score 2):

It is extremely common to capitalize such terms in rules, commentary and studies of games. Any reference to "a player" is usually left un-capitalized but a reference to "Player 1" typically is.

Miscellaneous examples:

> 1) Let us assume the first player is 1.
>
> 2) Let us assume Player 1 moves first.
>
> 3) Whenever a player moves [...]

A common *exception* to this rule is when the players will be referred to *without* the word "player":

> 4) Let us assume player 1 moves first. If 1 moves by doing [...]

This is more apparent when "A, B, C" are used instead of "1, 2, 3":

> 5) Let us assume player A moves first. If A moves by doing [...]

---

However, none of the above is encoded in a grammatical rule. My impressions of what is common comes from having read a great many manuals and instructions for games of all sorts.

If you are concerned about your *own* publication, then I recommend checking with your publication's style guides or with your editor. If you are merely concerned about someone else's usage, then they apparently disagreed with your personal style. There isn't a hard and fast rule on this subject.

... which isn't to say the subject is not worth studying from a user experience standpoint. I assume the advantage in capitalizing the term is to allow for better skimming. This could easily explain why (4, 5) do not capitalize while (2) does: The capitalization is telling you what to look for in the future.